# How to add auto increment(IDENTITY) to existing column in intersystems cache database

Tags: sql, database, ddl, intersystems-cache, intersystems

In intersystems cache, I have an existing table with example data as below

```
ID Name
1  Allen
2  Benny
```

I want to modify column ID so that it will be auto incremented. After adding this, if I insert charlie into the table then the id should be 3.

I think I have to use IDENTITY but not sure how to use it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change default ID column to anything else, you can use any other Property of class, and Index by this property which marked as [IdKey](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_index_idkey). But, you have to manage incrementing this property by yourself. And You can do it with [InitialExpression](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_property_initialexpression) for setting value for any new object even if it will not be saved, or in [%OnBeforeSave](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_callbacks#GOBJ_cb_onbeforesave) method, which will be called just before saving object.